# How do I fix element size change when doing 3D transforms?

Tags: html, css

I'm attemping some weird CSS effects involving 3D rotations and transforms to set up a scene.   This is basically a "menu".

HTML:  Each <li> tag contains a text label and I add :after in CSS to insert an image.

Problem:  The li element is so large I can't get to some other images "behind" it.  The image inserted is 100x160, and the label is drawn over the image itself, but the <li> element (according to the inspector) is 123.411 x 268.049.  The label is 123.411x268.049 (no idea why it has huge margins on top and bottom), and the image is showing to be 123.411x197.458 (due to perspective as I've pulled it to the front).  The 197 is OK.  The 268 is wasting 70 pixels ... blocking access to the next image.

Forcing the heights, even through javascript doesn't help.  It only alters the position (position is fixed anyway).  I'm about to give up and just make a big clickable image-map that overlays the whole thing, but will hurt my hover effects without using javascript.

```
Says it wants code to have a jsfiddle link, how stupid
```

Update: Try https://jsfiddle.net/6ut694yf/1/ (only a section of what I'm doing) and check the height of the candle.  Why is it so much larger than the image itself?  Hover effects demonstrate the problems.  You'll need a large screen to make the viewport wide enough so items aren't on top of each other as I've not yet added scaling for smaller screens (and mobile will have a whole different CSS, hence why all this is in CSS and not in HTML).

Comment: Some code and a fiddle or pen the recreates the issue would be helpful

Comment: Took me awhile to get enough in there to where you can see the problem. I was hoping someone has a simpler answer.  But the candle blocks the goddess because the browser thinks the candle is much taller than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good answer, so if someone has a better one, PLEASE let me know.  What I ended up doing was making a bunch of divs which I positioned over the images (a dozen of them) using the CSS calc() feature in order to attempt to keep the overlays lined up with the display of the images ... remember its 3D perspective and completely sized on the screen, so the actual calculations would be intense.  Even window height can affect horizontal position since the rotated plane will change size.  So you end up with positions like this:

```
[data-item="incense"] {
  top: calc(42vh - 65px);
  left: calc(70vw - 25px - 12vh);
  height: calc(35px + 12vh);
  width: calc(170px + 6vh);
  z-index: 5002;
}
```

Z-index lets the items overlap, using a higher Z-index for objects that are closer in space.   Then these items are added with class for position and display with no content.  A bit jQuery does this:

```
// hot is a temporary hack to correct 3D distortion of targets
    $(".hot").hover(function() {
            tagname = "#" + $(this).attr('data-item');
            $(tagname).addClass('hovered');
            $(tagname).trigger('mouseenter');
        }, function() {
            tagname = '#' + $(this).attr('data-item');
            $(tagname).removeClass('hovered');
            $(tagname).trigger("mouseleave");
        });
    $(".hot").click(function() {
            tagname = "#" + $(this).attr('data-item');
            $(tagname).trigger("click");
    });
```

The data-item attribute of the divs using the "hot" class (the clear overlays used for hot-spots) tie the hotspot to the actual item id being activated.  I then add a little extra CSS and create a ".hovered" class to duplicate the natural :hover effects.